# Get Video Attachment to post

Tags: posts, forms, attachments, videos

There is a plugin that let’s me upload a title, description and image with a form.

If you send it, it creates and automatic post with the title, description and the image.

The code for showing the image is:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() && is_single() ) { 
    $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' );
    ?>
    <div class="attachments">
        <p class="image-caption"> <?php _e('Ingezonden video:','feature-request'); ?> </p>
        <figure class="avfr-image post-image">
            <?php 
            echo '<a rel="lightbox" href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '">';
            the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );
            echo '</a>';
            ?>
```

I would like to rewrite the code so that I can upload a video and it automaticly posts the video , just like the image.

Can somebody help me with the code?

Answer (score -1):

Video from video clud, like youtube.com, vimeo? If true - use text field or textarea field. User fill youtube share code in this field and you will add this to post_content. Or create custom iframe and tell users insert video link.